# fzf.vim changing working directory on the fly

Tags: vim, fuzzy-search, fzf, vim-fzf

When I use `:Files` in fzf.vim, it searches for the files in the current directory and the subdirectories. The current working directory is fixed. In the screenshot below, it is in light blue. Is there a way to dynamically change the working directory on which FZF is run? For example, if I just delete "Documents" path, then FZF starts on ~ instead of ~/Documents.

Such functionality is possible in Emacs helm package, which allows this through helm-execute-persistent-action.

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is now possible with the reload action in fzf; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72946706/2144408 and https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/2872

Answer (score 9):

You could change the current working directory vim is currently using the `:chdir` or the familiar `:cd` command. See `:h cd` for more info.

And if you don't want to change the working directory of vim and just want fzf to use a different directory, you could run fzf (`:h fzf#run`) with a custom `dir` option.

This is an example mapping I have in my `~/.vimrc` to open a file within my `/.vim` directory:

```
nnoremap <leader>fv :call fzf#run({'options': '--reverse --prompt "VimFiles"', 'down': 20, 'dir': '~/.vim/', 'sink': 'e' })<CR>
```

For dynamic path you add a command that takes the path as an argument, make sure to use the completion as file for tab completing the path. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12636753/5006618) for more info on file completion.

The `sink` option tells what to do/perform when a match is found. and `e` is for editing the main window.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but isn't the question asking how to change the directory while the `fzf` window is still running?  I.e., being able to hit `backspace` (or `../`) without exiting the `fzf` window/starting over.

Comment: If @jdk1.0 is right, I read it's not possible. I can't find the source again but I stumbled on it looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Meanwhile there is a workaround proposed by the author. Take a look here:

> If you understand what fzf really is and how it works (it's a generic, context-free text filter running outside of Vim), you'll realize that it's not something we can easily implement with fzf. But you can experiment with `--expect` option or `reload` binding. I think this is the best we can do for the moment:
>
> ```
> " Reloading source on CTRL-P. Requires fd command.
> function! Foo(dir)
>   let tf = tempname()
>   call writefile(['.'], tf)
>
>   call fzf#vim#files(a:dir, {'source': 'fd', 'options': ['--bind', printf('ctrl-p:reload:base="$(cat %s)"/..; echo "$base" > %s; fd . "$base"', shellescape(tf), shellescape(tf))]})
> endfunction
>
> command! -nargs=* Foo call Foo(<q-args>)
> ```

https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/338#issuecomment-623087034