# fzf.vim: fuzzy matching with a fall-back source

Tags: vim, neovim, fzf, vim-fzf

I would like to implement a vim command to select buffers with the following behaviour:

1. When called, it present the user with a list of loaded buffers and other recently used buffers from the current directory (This is different from the `:History` command provided by `fzf.vim` in that we list only the recently used buffers from the current directory, fzf.vim lists all the recent buffers). The user can search for the file name they would like to load
2. If none of the options matches user's search term, expand the scope of the search by listing all the files in the current directory and letting the user fuzzy search through them.

This is what I have so far (This assumes that `junegunn/fzf.vim` is already installed):

```
nnoremap <silent> <space><space> :call <SID>recent_files()<CR>

function! s:recent_files_sink(items)
  if len(a:items) == 2
    execute "edit" a:items[1]
    return
  endif
  call fzf#vim#files("", {'options': ['--query', a:items[0]]})
endfunction

" deduped is a list of items without duplicates, this
" function inserts elements from items into deduped
function! s:add_unique(deduped, items)
  let dict = {}
  for item in a:deduped
    let dict[item] = ''
  endfor

  for f in a:items
    if has_key(dict, f) | continue | endif
    let dict[f] = ''
    call add(a:deduped, f)
  endfor
  return a:deduped
endfunction

function! s:recent_files()
  let regex = '^' . fnamemodify(getcwd(), ":p")
  let buffers = filter(map(
        \ getbufinfo({'buflisted':1}), {_, b -> fnamemodify(b.name, ":p")}),
        \ {_, f -> filereadable(f)}
        \ )
  let recent = filter(
        \ map(copy(v:oldfiles), {_, f -> fnamemodify(f, ":p")}),
        \ {_, f -> filereadable(f) && f =~# regex})
  let combined = s:add_unique(buffers, recent)
  call fzf#run(fzf#wrap({
        \ 'source': map(combined, {_, f -> fnamemodify(f, ":~:.")}),
        \ 'sink*': function('s:recent_files_sink'),
        \ 'options': '--print-query --exit-0 --prompt "Recent> "'
        \ }))
endfunction
```

<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> invokes `s:recent_files()` which lists loaded buffers and recently used files from viminfo. The interesting bit here is the `sink*` option in the call to `fzf#run` (4th line from the bottom). The sink is another function. If a filename was selected, the sink function loads it for editing, otherwise, it calls `fzf#vim#files`, which lists the contents of the directory.

This is pretty close to what I want but there are a couple of problems:

1. When no matches are found in recent files, the user must press <kbd>Return</kbd> to trigger the fall-back. (One can easily argue that this is the correct behaviour)
2. When the fall-back fzf window is loaded, it starts in the normal mode and not the insert mode
3. <s>The user must enter the search query again in the new fzf window</s> (solved)

I'm looking for suggestions on how to solve these problems, particularly 2 and 3. I'm also open to solutions that don't meet the specifications exactly but provide a good user experience.

**EDIT**: I came up with another approach to achieve this using this as the source for fzf

```
cat recent_files.txt fifo.txt
```

where `recent_files.txt` is a list of recent files and `fifo.txt` is an empty fifo created using `mkfifo`. A mapping can be added to buffer which  triggers a command to write to the fifo. This way, the user can use that mapping to include a list of all files in case they don't find a match in  recent files. This approach becomes problematic in cases where user finds the file in recents and presses enter. Since fzf is till waiting to read  from fifo, it does not exit https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/2288

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to come to a solution that is pretty close using fzf's `reload` functionality. (Thanks to [junegunn](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/2872))

This is how it goes:

```
nnoremap <silent> <space><space> :call <SID>recent_files()<CR>

" Initialize fzf with a list of loaded buffers and recent files from
" the current directory. If <space> is pressed, we load a list of all
" the files in the current directory
function! s:recent_files()
  let regex = '^' . fnamemodify(getcwd(), ":p")
  let buffers = filter(map(
        \ getbufinfo({'buflisted':1}), {_, b -> fnamemodify(b.name, ":p")}),
        \ {_, f -> filereadable(f)}
        \ )
  let recent = filter(
        \ map(copy(v:oldfiles), {_, f -> fnamemodify(f, ":p")}),
        \ {_, f -> filereadable(f) && f =~# regex})
  let combined = <SID>add_unique(buffers, recent)

  "-------------------------------------------
  " This is the key piece that makes it work
  "-------------------------------------------
  let options = [
        \ '--bind', 'space:reload:git ls-files',
        \ ]

  call fzf#run(fzf#wrap({
        \ 'source': map(combined, {_, f -> fnamemodify(f, ":~:.")}),
        \ 'options': options
        \ }))
endfunction

" deduped is a list of items without duplicates, this
" function inserts elements from items into deduped
function! s:add_unique(deduped, items)
  let dict = {}
  for item in a:deduped
    let dict[item] = ''
  endfor

  for f in a:items
    if has_key(dict, f) | continue | endif
    let dict[f] = ''
    call add(a:deduped, f)
  endfor
  return a:deduped
endfunction
```

I start FZF by using `<space><space>`. This FZF window contains only the most recent files from the current directory. If I then press `<space>`,  the FZF window is updated  with a new list of files obtained from `git ls-files`.

---

**Update: Apr 2023**

FZF now supports a `zero` event. It is triggered when no match is  found. This can be used to trigger a `reload` like the example above does with `space`

Comment: this script is phenomenally useful; I really love this idea of starting with a shortlist and then pressing space to expand to all git tracked files. I'm currently modifying it to be able to pass along an additional filter on files. That way, I can have separate bindings per filetype, and potentially also one for 'whatever filetype I am currently in' which would be the most common kind of filesearch for me.

Comment: I made your script into a plugin, with a few improvements: [`Plug 'TamaMcGlinn/vim-fuzzy-recent'`](https://github.com/TamaMcGlinn/vim-fuzzy-recent) So binding to fuzzy_recent#Find() is equivalent to your binding, but you can also go by filetype or do something custom with the result. Enjoy!

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful. This is a pretty old version of what I have now. Happy to share the latest one if you would like

Comment: sure, it would be interesting to hear what issues you have run into and fixed, since I've just started using this

Comment: Here's my most recent version: https://pastebin.com/u9kD76X8. Most notably, this does not require pressing <Space> to load all files. It happens automatically if there's no match in recent files (the <Space> binding is still present)

Comment: why did you switch from git ls-files to just ls-files?

Comment: overall it's great improvements and I have put them into the plugin as well; I like the prompts, the 40% height at the bottom, but just 'ls-files' doesn't work. We could add a third level, going from git ls-files to `find . -type f` to list also gitignored files.

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned, ls-files is a custom script which switches between `git ls-files`, `fd` and `find` depending on what is installed and if I am in a git repo